# pick the minimum value out of a list of sublists and display another value in that sublist with the minimum

Tags: python, list, selection, minimum

Say I have a list:

```
stuff =  [[5,3,8],[2,4,7],[14,5,9]]
```

where each sublist is of the form `[x,y,z]`.

I want to find the minimum value of this list for the third entry in the sub lists, i.e. `z=7`. Then I want to print out the first value of that sublist, `x`.

ex) The minimum value of z occurs at `x = 2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function with the `key` parameter, like this

```
stuff = [[5,3,8],[2,4,7],[14,5,9]]
print min(stuff, key = lambda x: x[2])[0]   # 2
```

To make this more readable, you can unpack the values like this

```
print min(stuff, key = lambda (x, y, z): z)[0]
```

For each and every element of stuff, the function assigned to `key` parameter will be invoked. Now, the minimum value will be determined based on the value returned by that function only.

Comment: Excellent, it works. Thank you, but could you tell me what key = lambda does?

Comment: @BobUnger Please check the answer for a short explanation and also go through the documentation link I have provided for `min`. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the built-in `min` function a `key` to access the third element in each sublist:

**Demo**

```
>>> stuff = [[5,3,8],[2,4,7],[14,5,9]]
>>> x, y, z = min(stuff, key=lambda arr: arr[2])
>>> x, y, z
(2, 4, 7)
```